# Scaling delimiters in MathJax

Tags: tex4ht, mathjax, mathml

I use TeX4ht with MathJax to convert tex to HTML/MathML. One issue I have is that delimiters scale depending on the height of the line, even if the tall content is not between the delimiters. For instance, compiling the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
    f(x) = \frac{\frac{x}{1}}{\frac{2}{3}} 
\]
\end{document}
```

with

```
htlatex test "cf,mathjax"
```

yields

[image]

Here `cf.cfg` just contains

```
\Preamble{html,mathml}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

I think the parentheses are too large. Is there a way to control the scaling?

Comment: if you use `\Preamble{xhtml}` instead, then it works as is. But may be you want `mathml` for other reasons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As David Carlisle said, this is a bug in TeX4ht. `<mo>` elements around parentheses should have set the `stretchy="false"` attribute. I will fix that in TeX4ht sources. Until this fix is added to TeX Live, you can use the following `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,mathjax}
\catcode`\:=11
\Configure{MathClass}{4}{*}{<\a:mathml mo\Hnewline
          \mml:class="MathClass-open" stretchy="false">}
                        {</\a:mathml mo>}{}
\Configure{MathClass}{5}{*}{<\a:mathml mo\Hnewline
          \mml:class="MathClass-close" stretchy="false">}
                        {</\a:mathml mo>}{}
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

BTW, I would recommend to use `make4ht` instead of `htlatex`, because it fixes some issues with MathML that are impossible to fix on the TeX side. So you can compile your file using:

```
make4ht -c cf.cfg test "mathml,mathjax"
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Note for anyone reading without the rep to see my deleted answer. I originally posted a kludge to force the right output, but I have deleted it as people should do this instead:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and also pointed me into the right direction, because I would spend much more time if I had to figure out the correct MathML code myself :)

Comment: Since this example works as is when using `\Preamble{xhtml}` instead of `\Preamble{mathml}` I was wondering, what is the advantage if any to using `mathml` vs. `xhtml`? I've never used `mathml` myself, that is why I never seen this problem. Is there a reason to use `mathml` over  `xhtml`? if you think this should be separate question, will do do. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser when you use custom commands, you don't need to pass them to MathJax when you use MathML. It can be also rendered faster in the browser. But I think you can continue to use MathJax, as you have working configurations for that. You probably won't find too many advantages in MathML.